# How to pass the output value of databricks notebook as a string to data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have a databricks notebook `Notebook1` in which I have written a query to fetch the `last_mod_time` from databricks data table and saved it as a dataframe.

Now, I have created a pipeline in azure data factory and using the output of that notebook to pass the `last_mod_time` value as a string to an IF condition activity.

Can you guys please suggest a way through which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided if you are returning the last_mod_time from your notebook activity, you can access the output of the activity using,

@activity.yourdatabricksactivityname.output.last_mod_time

You can use the above expression in the IF activity condition

Comment: Hi @mani_nz. Thanks for you input, I was able to get the last_mod_time by ending my notebook query with dbutils.notebook.exit(df). When I ran the notebook activity in data factory, I was able to get the notebook result as runOutput which I used to pass on other activity.

Comment: Glad it helped. Pls accept the answer to help others :)